# OpenWRT missing OD (octal dump)

Tags: bash, sed, openwrt, od

I have a bash function using **od** command.

Now I'm trying to run in on OpenWRT and see that in has not od.
Also can't find it using install from opkg, because I can't find it.
Is there a possibility to install it manually?

I also know about **sed** but are not that familiar with it.
Is it possible to do this exact task:

```
function format {
#1=data type (like u1) 2=How much bytes 3=byte starting position in file 4=file
       od -An -t $1 -N $2 -j $3 $4
}
```

Comment: Do you have `xxd`?

Comment: While doing this with sed is theoretically possible, since sed is Turing-complete, it would involve an inordinate amount of code, including matching each character to its hex/octal/decimal code. There probably is a package with `od`. Isn't it included in your BusyBox binary? If not you can install [the one from coreutils](http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages/packages/coreutils-od_8.16-1_ar71xx.ipk).

Comment: @Gilles That was the package name I was searching for! `opkg install coreutils-od` did the trick. Somehow I did not find it in the list of possible packages in the first place (I am new to opkg-package manager)! Thank you!